# Laravel 6: trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

> Error: Trying to get property 'gender_id' of non-object

**Controller:**

```
public function printreports(Request $request)
{
$id = $request->get('select2'); //eg. id=1
$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->find($id);
return view('teachers.report1',compact('teachers'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($teachers as $teacher)
{{$teacher->gender_id}}
@endforeach
```

while if i do it with Eloquent by replacing following query it works, but i want to do it with DB query as stated above.

```
$teachers = Teacher::find($id);
```

Comment: find return list of data by dd, and eloquent returns list of array within array and then list of data.

Comment: You are fetching single record so no need for loop

Comment: show screen dd $teachers when you use DB facade

Comment: if you only want 1 teacher, by id, why are you naming it `teachers` ... you are trying to iterate a single object again, which will iterate the public properties .. you don't have a collection

Comment: sometime i return many teachers from controller, that's just an example.

Comment: you are using `find()`,it will return only one record

Comment: problem solved thanks

Comment: so you are potentially trying to find multiple records? seems you passed an array to `Teacher::find()`

Comment: i was testing to find one

Comment: i was passing one id

Comment: one id in an array ... passing an array to `find` on `Model` causes it to handle it like you are trying to find many, which will return a Collection ... ends up calling `findMany`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need use where, and after it you will have collection.

```
$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

when you use find, you have single item

Comment: Thank you it worked. what was issue with that can you tell please.

Comment: When you use DB::table('teachers')->find($id) , it return single model or null. But when you use where() and ->get() it return collection models.

When you try foreach single model, you fetch public properties you model and have error, when use properties as object

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me why it return only one id's data? i am passing multiple ids from select.

Comment: this is returning only one id's data, everything else is same.$id = $request->get('select2');

                  $teachers = DB::table('teachers')->where('id', $id)->get();
                  dd($teachers);

Comment: $id - is array with id's ?

Comment: if i dd($id) it has  0 => "112"
  1 => "117"  id, and query shows only 112 result.

Comment: ok, just use whereIn
DB::table('teachers')->whereIn('id', $id)->get();

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `foreach` while you use `find()`.

```
 @if(sizeof($teachers))
 {{$teachers->gender_id}}
 {{$teachers->gender_id}}//whatever field you need to display
 {{$teachers->gender_id}}//whatever field you need to display

 @endif
```

If you use `get()`,

```
$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

@if(sizeof($teachers))
@foreach($teachers as $teacher)
 {{$teacher->gender_id}}
 {{$teacher->gender_id}}//whatever field you need to display
 {{$teacher->gender_id}}//whatever field you need to display

@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: gender_id is just an example, i have list of columns. and id's.

Answer (score 0):

`$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->find($id);` will return a single Model or  `null`, try using `$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return collection to view then use `get()` method like this:-

```
public function printreports(Request $request)
{
$id = $request->get('select2'); 
$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->where('id', $id)->get();
return view('teachers.report1',compact('teachers'));
}
```